# Custom shortcut that maps to a command in the context menu of Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

How can I define a new keyboard shortcut with Autohotkey that will map to a certain command which resides in the context menu of Chrome?

The command that I want to invoke belongs to a plugin, called Evernote Clipper, of Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try sending a right click and then select the correct menu entry sending arrows keys or the first characters of the entry name. Something like:

```
MyHotkey::
Click Right
SendInput {down %N%}{Enter}
return
```

N has the entry index and MyHotkey is obviously the hotkey that you want to use for example
`^k`